# App above all anothers

Tags: android

with which functionality of Android is it possible to make a App callable from everywhere like the Facebook Messenger Chat:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have a "full app" above all others. However, you can achieve a convincing simulacrum with a trick.

Applications with the android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW (displayed as "draw over other apps" in Play Store) can create windows from a service and show them over all other content.

There is an open source library called [StandOut](https://github.com/pingpongboss/StandOut) which provides this behavior in an easy to use manner. You might want to take a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

That's called Chatheads and uses a custom `Window` backed up by a `Service`. Then you need to implement your click logic and bring up an activity (with an `Intent`).

A good tutorial is [here](http://www.piwai.info/chatheads-basics/)